# Mixing Future and F[] inside a for comprehension

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have hit a problem withe my for comprehension as follows:

```scala
  def doSomething(): F[String] = {

    for {
      _ <- Future.traverse(items)(item => doSomeWork(item)) // Future[]
      _ <- doSomeOtherWork(42)  //F[]
    } yield (())

  }
```

The function `doSomeWork` looks like:

```scala
  def doSomeWork(item: Item): Future[Unit] =
         // some work done inside a Future
    )
```

and the function `doSomeOtherWork` work looks like:

```scala
    def doSomeOtherWork(i : Int): F[Unit]
```

So when I try to compile I hit the following error:

```scala
[error]  found   : F[Int]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
[error]       
[error]         ^
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]
[error]  required: F[Int]
```

Am i not allowed to mix F[] and Future inside a for comp like this?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.
A **for comprehension** is just *sugar syntax* for calls to `flatMap` & `map`. And those only work on the same monad.

The best you can do, if you can not change `doSomeWork` to return an `F`, is to convert your futures into `Fs` on the for.

Here is an example of how you may do that.
*(I had to invent many details because your questions was very vague)*

```
import cats.effect.{Async, ContextShift, Sync}
import cats.instances.list._ // Provides the Foldable[List] instance into scope.
import cats.syntax.flatMap._ // Provides the flatMap method (used in the for).
import cats.syntax.foldable._ // Provides the traverse_ method.
import cats.syntax.functor._ // Provides the map method (used in the for).
import scala.concurrent.Future

final case class Item(id: Int, name: String)

def doSomeWork(item: Item): Future[Unit] = ???

def doSomeOtherWork[F[_] : Sync](i: Int): F[Unit] = ???

def doSomething[F[_]](items: List[Item])(implicit F: Async[F], cs: ContextShift[F]): F[Unit] =
  for {
    _ <- items.traverse_(item => Async.fromFuture(F.delay(doSomeWork(item))))
    _ <- doSomeOtherWork(42)
  } yield ()
```

Tested with **cats-effect** `2.0.0`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that doSomeWork calls another method inside (Play request) which returns a Future - so that's why doSomeWork returns Future[Unit]

Comment: @Mojo yeah that is why I showed you how to keep using future.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Since a for comprehension is just syntactic sugar for map and flatMap calls, your program actually looks like this:

```
(_: Future[Int]).flatMap(doSomeOtherWork).map(())
```

And since `Future.flatMap` expects a function returning a Future again, your program is rejected by the compiler.